# Prodcuing a list of variables based on the user's input

Tags: r

I have a function that converts user's input (via `readline()`) into a list of variables. There are 2 situations that I would definitely like R to deal with:

1. User provides a range of numbers that will occupy one slot in a list
2. User provides a range of numbers and each number will occupy a separate slot in a list.

Code is below:

```
library(stringr)
translatingVar<-function(answer,varList){# 'answer' is the user's input and 'varList' is a name that will store user's input
  var1<-NULL
  bool<-0
  y<-0
  varA<-list()
  answer<-strsplit(answer,",",fixed = TRUE)# splitting a string of input into separate intended inputs 
  for(i in 1:length(answer[[1]])){# 'for' loop to process each input
    answer[[1]][i]<-str_remove_all(answer[[1]][i],"[ ]")# removing any empty spaces
    if(is.na(as.numeric(answer[[1]][i]))){#checking if input can be translated to numeric format straight away
      if(!length(grep("all",answer[[1]][i],fixed=TRUE))>0){#Tried to create a variable to separate 2 situations.
        bool<-1
      }
#Here are bunch of 'if' functions that process different scenarios
      if(!length(grep(":",answer[[1]][i],fixed=TRUE))>0){
        varA[[i+y]]<-answer[[1]][i]
      }else if(grep(":",answer[[1]][i],fixed=TRUE)&bool==1){
        varA[[i+y]]<-c(as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],":",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]):as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],":",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2]))
      }else if(grep("all",answer[[1]][i],fixed=TRUE)){
        answer[[1]][i]<-str_remove_all(answer[[1]][i],"[all ]")
        var1<-as.list(c(as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],":",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]):as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],":",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2])))
        varA<-append(varA,var1)
        y<-length(var1)
      }else{
        varA[[i+y]]<-answer[[1]][i]
      }

    }else{
      varA[[i+y]]<-as.numeric(answer[[1]][i])
    }

  }
  assign(varList,varA,envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
ss<-readline()
translatingVar(ss,"Variables")
```

Currently, I am receiving the following error:

```
Error in as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i], ":", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]):as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],  : 
  NA/NaN argument
```

I believe it means that `answer[[1][i]` is empty, hence further actions are impossible. I tried to move 'if' functions around and play with extra variables to help R identify different scenarios better but with not much success.

Desired outcome:

input - "1,2,3:5,all 6:8,9"

output - list(1,2,c(3:5),6,7,8,9)

Answer (score 0):

At a closer look, I've noticed that a `bool` variable is outside of a for loop which means it is not overwritten on each iteration.

Corrected code below:

```
translatingVar<-function(answer,varList){
  var1<-NULL
  y<-0
  varA<-list()
  answer<-strsplit(answer,",",fixed = TRUE)
  for(i in 1:length(answer[[1]])){
    answer[[1]][i]<-str_remove_all(answer[[1]][i],"[ ]")
    bool<-0
    if(is.na(as.numeric(answer[[1]][i]))){
      if(!length(grep("all",answer[[1]][i],fixed=TRUE))>0){
        bool<-1
      }
      if(!length(grep(":",answer[[1]][i],fixed=TRUE))>0){
        varA[[i+y]]<-answer[[1]][i]
      }else if(grep("all",answer[[1]][i],fixed=TRUE)&&bool==0){
        answer[[1]][i]<-str_remove_all(answer[[1]][i],"[all ]")
        var1<-as.list(c(as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],":",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]):as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],":",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2])))
        varA<-append(varA,var1)
        y<-length(var1)
      }else if(grep(":",answer[[1]][i],fixed=TRUE)&&bool==1){
        varA[[i+y]]<-c(as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],":",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]):as.numeric(strsplit(answer[[1]][i],":",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2]))
      }else{
        varA[[i+y]]<-answer[[1]][i]
      }

    }else{
      varA[[i+y]]<-as.numeric(answer[[1]][i])
    }

  }
  if(!length(which(lapply(varA,is.null)==TRUE))>0){
    assign(varList,varA,envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
  assign(varList,varA[-which(lapply(varA,is.null)==TRUE)],envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```